# Doc2vec LSTM accuracy does not improve

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, lstm, doc2vec

```
print(X.shape,y.shape)
(2591, 300) (2591,)
```

I have this shape X,y 
 this is Doc2vec matrix

I tried LogisticRegression,MLPClassifier this gives around 80% accuracy

```
I choose to build 3 hidden layers
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(unknown, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=300))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2 ))
model.add(Dense(len(dic), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but when I tried the LSTM the accuracy does not improve

> Epoch 1/100 2591/2591 [==============================] - 5s 2ms/step -
>   loss: 1.5062 - accuracy: 0.3547 Epoch 2/100 2591/2591
>   [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 1.5079 -
>   accuracy: 0.3551 Epoch 3/100 2591/2591
>   [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 1.5057 -
>   accuracy: 0.3547 Epoch 4/100 2591/2591
>   [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 1.5089 -
>   accuracy: 0.3547 Epoch 5/100 2591/2591
>   [==============================] - 5s 2ms/step - loss: 1.5062 -
>   accuracy: 0.3547 Epoch 6/100

in this case what is the problem?

Comment: 2,591 documents is a pretty small corpus for `Doc2Vec` – & I suspect really tiny for an LSTM network, which, by my understanding, needs **lots** of data to train. (It also looks like you're comparing 300-dimensional `Doc2Vec`-based embeddings with just 100-dimensional embeddings from the LSTM-based approach, which could be a factor.

Comment: I did not tried the transformer or bert. so small data is not good for lstm or bert? its better with classification or LogisticRegression?

Comment: All of these techniques do better with more training data, and larger/deeper models need even more data & training time.